# Reason regarding error

Tags: error

I came to know that there is some error in the bold part of following sentence.What could be the reason?

The language used for writing textbooks differs from other forms of writings **in its preference** on simplicity over style

Answer (score 1):

It's not the bolded part of the sentence that contains the error -- it's the preposition right after the bold part.  "preference on" is incorrect; we say "preference for."